# Read certificate passed to a NestJS API Method

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, nestjs

I am creating an API in NestJS to act as middleware between my backend and some other 3rd party APIs. Now to authenticate the API calls from 3rd party, I want to read the certificate that they will pass alongwith the request. I am able to get the request working without the certificate but can't find a way to read a certificate passed along with this request.

Can someone here please help in letting my NestJS API method accept a certificate and read it's content for authentication.

Comment: Please post relevant code, explain exactly how it fails and provide relevant error messages.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Unfortunately I don't even know where to start. All I have is below API method. How do I try to read certificate attached to this request. When I call this API via code or via postman, the query gets executed successfully but I don't know how to read the certificate attached with it.

@ApiQuery({ name: 'form_id', type: 'number', required: true })
@Get('get-data-for-form')
  async getDataForForm(@Query('form_id') form_id: number) {
    try {
//Do Something
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)

      }
    }
  }

Comment: Please do not put a bunch of code in a comment, edit the question instead.